# Locking ID before doing an insert - Oracle 10G

Tags: oracle10g, locking, sequence

I have a table whose primary keys are numbers are not sequentially. 
By company policy is to register the new rows with ID lower value available. I.E.

```
table.ID = [11,13,14,16,17]
min(table.ID) = 12
```

I have an algorithm that gives me the lowest available. I want to know how to prevent this ID is use by another person before making insertion.

Would it be possible to do by DB? or would it be programming language?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what "BD" is supposed to stand for here.  How would it be done in anything other than software?  Are you looking for a hardware solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company policy is extremely short-sighted.  Unless the company's goal is to build applications that do not scale and the company is unconcerned with performance.

If you really wanted to do this, you'd need to serialize all your transactions that touch this table-- essentially turning your nice, powerful server into a single-threaded single-user low-end machine.  There are any number of ways to do this. The simplest (though not simple) method would be to do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the row with the largest key less than the new key you want to insert (11 in this case).  Once you acquired the lock, you would need to re-confirm that 12 is vacant.  If it is, you could then insert the row with an `id` of 12.  Otherwise, you'd need to restart the process looking for the new key and trying to lock the row with an `id` one less than that key.  When your transaction commits, the lock would be released and the next session that was blocked waiting for a lock would be able to process.  This assumes that you can control every process that tries to insert data into this table and that they would all implement exactly the same logic.  It will lock up the system if you ever allow transactions to span waits for human input because humans will inevitably go to lunch with rows locked.  And all that serialization will radically reduce the scalability of your application.

I would strongly encourage you to push back against the ridiculous "requirement" rather than implementing something this hideous.